# Mapping a Map<String,List<Foo>> in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Considering the following object:

```
Keyword{
  int id;
  String area;
  String keyword;
  Article article;
}
```

What is the best way to Map the following association in Hibernate, where the map's key should be Keyword.area:

```
Article{
  private Map<String,List<Keyword>> keywords = new HashMap<String, List<Keyword>>();
}
```

It is straightforward if it was a Map, but in this situation I will mostly need to access the keywords by area (e.g. article.findAll("science") to return all science keywords).

The best idea I've had so far is to transform the former into

```
private Map<String,KeywordGroup> keywords = new HashMap<String, KeywordGroup>();
```

but this leaves me with some questions, like:

- Properties in KeywordGroup? Logically it would be composed of "area" and List, but how to map this?
- The simplest database design for this is to have a FK column in Keyword for article_id, won't KeywordGroup complicate this?

What approach would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following implementation of Article would work for you, without the need for a Map.

```
@Entity
public class Article {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="article")
    private Set<Keyword> keywords;

    //..

    public Set<Keyword> findKeywordsByArea(String area) {

        Set<Keyword> matchingKeywords = new HashSet<Keyword>();
        for(Keyword keyword : this.keywords) {
            if(keyword.getArea().equals(area)) {
                matchingKeywords.add(keyword);
            }
        }
        return matchingKeywords;
    }
}
```

Comment: Spot on for that, thank you for the suggestion - this was something I thought about too. However, won't this raise performance issues - namely, having to query the entire set of the article's keywords every time I want to findKeywordsByArea? 
Perhaps I will encounter the same performance issues with the other approach, I just don't want to run into any N+1 select or similar problems.

Comment: I would get something working before worrying about performance. Instead of iterating over the entire keyword set you could write a custom HQL query.

Comment: I am accepting this answer. Even though I might need to revisit this in the future, I'm adopting the KISS strategy and I will worry with performance when the time comes.